# document.documentElement.appendChild() does not work

Tags: javascript, svg

I tried some simple examples like the following one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20010904//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <![CDATA[

      function test() {
        var svgElement = document.documentElement;
        var tnode = document.createTextNode('thx for the click');
        var t = document.createElement('text');
        t.setAttribute('x','20');
        t.setAttribute('y','32');
        t.setAttribute('class','ext');
        t.setAttribute('id','text1');
        t.appendChild(tnode);
        svgElement.appendChild(t);
      }
    ]]>
    </script>
  </defs>
  <rect width="100" height="100" y="50" x="50" onclick="test();" />
</svg>
```

This one shows a rectangle and if you click, test() gets executed (see running version [here](http://hala.li/test2.svg)). As I see on the DOM with Firebug, the new element gets actually appended:

[image: Screenshot of Firebug]

But the error is - it does not get showed! Why does it get appended but not shown? I've spent so much time in this problem, but no idea.

I copied this example out of a SVG workshop and I tried it in Chrome and Firefox.

Please help :/

Comment: I am sure. You can watch at the sample at http://hala.li/test2.svg

Comment: As @SomekidwithHTML mentioned earlier, it seems to work if you define a color for it as well. http://img339.imageshack.us/img339/6680/svgc.png

Comment: @FabrícioMatté jsfiddle is not a svg document

Comment: @Esailija Yeah my bad, didn't notice it was a svg document earlier. `=]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create the element in the SVG namespace i.e.

```
var t = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'text');
```